# what is equivalent lock from oracle in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, locking

In Oracle is:

```
LOCK TABLE employees IN EXCLUSIVE MODE WAIT 10;
```

On employees table I have to do first delete and then insert.

```
LOCK TABLE employees ..
DELETE FROM employees ..
INSERT INTO employees ...
```

What is equivalent statement of LOCK in ms sql server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE 

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM employees .. 
INSERT INTO employees ... 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Either the delete statement will succeed and lock the table exclusively, or it will fail (if a lock is already held by another connection).

BTW, it's good practice to try and avoid such extreme exclusive locking. There are other less aggressive isolation levels that you might possibly be able to use with the same results.

See [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: And `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000` first for the `WAIT 10`